# @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class}) does not rollback transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, rollback, transactional

I have the following piece of code where I am using Spring's @Transactional annotation with JDBC template and it does not rollback a transaction. I have used random file names and table name. I am trying to delete a row for a Foreign key id and then insert a record for the same id in a database table named "data". But when I was testing I am seeing that if there is an error in the insert, the delete does not get rollbacked. 
I am pretty new to Spring, so any help would be appreciated.

TestService.java

```
   @Service
   public class TestService {

      @Autowired
      TestRepository testRepository;

      @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
      public void insertData(List<Data> dataList, Integer fkId)
         throws Exception {
         testRepository.updateData(dataList, fkId);
         //do some other stuff
      }
 }
```

TestRepository.java

```
 @Respository
 public class TestRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataJdbcTemplate")
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate dataJdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
     public void updateData(List<Data> dataList, Integer fkId) 
        throws Exception {

         String deleteId = "DELETE FROM data where 
        fk_id = :fkId";

         dataJdbcTemplate.update(deleteId, new 
           MapSqlParameterSource("fkId", fkId));

         String sql = "INSERT INTO data(fk_id, column1, column2)"
            + " VALUES(:fkId, :column1, :column2)";

         SqlParameterSource[] batch = 
SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(dataList.toArray());
    dataJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, batch);


 }
```

database.xml

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="dataJdbcTemplate" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.
      NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try enabling transaction propagation.

You can read more here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Comment: I tried adding  @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class}, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED) in repository method but doesn't work.